# Visual Studio crashes when creating new keystore

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to sign my Xamarin App in Visual Studio, acoording to https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=macos

When I try to create a new keystore, I fill the form and click ok, but the new keystore is not created. The list remains empty.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

I would expect the following to happen:

> The resulting keystore resides in the following location:
>
> ~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/Keystore/alias/alias.keystore
>
> For example, the above steps might create a new signing key in the > following location:
>
> ~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/Keystore/chimp/chimp.keystore

But I dont even have this path "~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/Keystore/" created

Comment: Checked the IDE logs for details of the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess, you may need to replace `Developer` with your actual username

and most likely also unhide the `~/Library` folder, which is hidden by default.

[image: Screenshot]

Image Source: [macworld.com](https://www.macworld.com/article/2057221/how-to-view-the-library-folder-in-mavericks.html)

Comment: thanks, I 'm new to development in mac and didn't know that folder was hidden. But the folder Developer exists within my user's Library.

Comment: I've found the keystore there. The problem now is this VS 2019 last update which is apparently with some bug. All of a sudden it get slow, and can't show the dialog to select the keystore generated above. There is some trouble with this sign app dialog in VS 2019, it simply crashes VS

Comment: Apparently it's s problem with VS 2019. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/518694/view.html. Going back to 2017.

Comment: downgrading seems to make sense in this case, because an unstable IDE is unacceptable.

Comment: :( Even 2017 is crashing... When I click "Import an existing key" it just closes. How can I sign the apk via command line?

Comment: you cannot sign anything, unless having an accessible key-store - and we probably cannot help you much, unless you'd tell us **why** it crashes. the comment below the question does not tell much else. "it crashes" is not an error description. there also should be a `keytool` on OSX.

Comment: All I know is that, i dont know where the app log is located so I could paste something here. By now I've got to create the keystore. Trying to sign via command line.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/manually-signing-the-apk ...it seems that build-tools `25.0.3` need to be installed.